# The listview not showing any SMS data any more?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, sms

I had my list view to show all the SMS earlier but after re-running the app...the list view is showing empty for some reason any idea why I'm getting blank screen and how can I fix this issue?

```
package com.example.sunny.messager;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class ListActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

            ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.SmsList);

            if(fetchInbox()!=null){
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fetchInbox());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
        public ArrayList<String> fetchInbox(){

            ArrayList<String> sms=new ArrayList<String>();

            Uri uriSms=Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

            Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id","address","date","body"}, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                String address=cursor.getString(1);
                String body=cursor.getString(3);

                sms.add("Address: " +address+"\n Sms: " +body);
            }
            return sms;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try just using "content://sms/".

Comment: no problem at all. I also posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your Inbox is empty. Try just using "content://sms/" and
see if you can get any items.

Also, your code is calling fetchInbox function twice.
You can try the following to make it more efficient.

```
ArrayList<String> aItems = fetchInbox():
if ( aItems.size() > 0 )
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aItems);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```